# Как можно сослаться на страницу в латехе?

Tags: links

Как можно сослаться на страницу в латехе? Именно на страницу, а не на метку. Я имею PDF фотографии, которые включены в латех документ, они занимают много страниц. Перед этим документом я хочу создать список, кликая на нужное название чтобы можно было перейти на ту страницы, на которой расположена нужная фотография. Здесь не нужна никакая автоматика. Нужную страницу я укажу сам, вот только как сделать такую ссылку?

Пытаюсь так, но это не то, что нужно.

> **Google Translate (typos corrected)**

> How can I link to a page in LaTeX? It is on the page, not on the label. I have PDF photos that are included in the latex document, they occupy many pages. Before this document, I want to create a list by clicking on the desired name so that you can go to the page on which the desired photo is located. No automation is needed here. I will indicate the necessary page myself, but how to make such a link?

```
\usepackage[unicode, pdftex]{hyperref} % Пакет для подключения ссылок
\includepdf{photo.pdf}
\hypertarget{d6}{4}
```

Comment: Здравствуй, Антон! Please note that the *lingua franca* on TeX.SX is English, so all posts should be in English. Unfortunately, we can't answer questions in other languages. Would it be possible to translate your question into English?

Comment: Hrmmm... I think it would have been nice to wait a bit with the downvote. A quick look on Google translate suggests this is a genuine question and not a foreign-language spamming attempt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking a text to a page (by page number)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19412/linking-a-text-to-a-page-by-page-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking on the page-number link (so next to the desired name, like the table of contents does):

Use the package option `pageanchor` to place an anchor at top left of every page, then use command `\hyperpage{x}`, where `x`= page number, to make the link.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pageanchor]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
x first page

Go to page \hyperpage{4}

\newpage
y second page
\newpage
z third page
\newpage
abc : go to page \hyperpage{1}

The fourth page.

\end{document}
```

Comment: unless I misunderstand here, using `\hyperpage` like that hard-codes the page number. Is there a more robust way, so that when content changes, the link will still point to the (new) page that was the original target?

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Это именно то, что я хотел!